# Custom component having a text field and a selection field using React MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like to create a custom component that can use a text field and a field to select some option using React MUI, I have searched in the library but I haven't found anything, also I tried to do it and it doesn't look good here is my code:

```
<TextField
  value={value.text}
  onChange={onChange}
  {...rest}
  InputProps={{
  endAdornment: (
    <InputAdornment position='end'>
      <TextField
        select
        name='option'
        value={value.option}
        onChange={onChange}
        {...selectProps}
        sx={{ '.MuiSelect-select': { border: 'none' } }}
       >
         {options.map((option) => (
         <MenuItem key={option} value={option}>
           {option}
         </MenuItem>
       ))}
      </TextField>
    </InputAdornment>
    ),
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const TextFieldWithOptions = ({
  textFieldValue = 'text',
  optionFieldValue = 'option',
  value = { [textFieldValue]: '', [optionFieldValue]: '' },
  name,
  options,
  onChange,
  buttonProps,
  menuProps,
  ...rest
}: TextFieldWithOptionsProps) => {
  const [valueState, setValueState] = useState(value);

  const onChangeValueStateHandler = useCallback(({ target }: any) => {
    setValueState((prev: any) => ({
      ...prev,
      [target.name]: target.value,
    }));
  }, []);

  console.log(valueState);

  return (
    <FlexBox gap={4} alignItems={'center'} justifyContent={'center'}>
      <TextField
        id='text-field'
        name={textFieldValue}
        value={valueState[textFieldValue]}
        onChange={onChangeValueStateHandler}
        InputProps={{
          endAdornment: (
            <InputAdornment position='end'>
              <OptionMenu
                optionFieldValue={optionFieldValue}
                initialOption={valueState[optionFieldValue]}
                options={options}
                onChange={onChangeValueStateHandler}
              />
            </InputAdornment>
          ),
        }}
        {...rest}
      />
    </FlexBox>
  );
};
```

```
const OptionMenu = ({
  initialOption,
  optionFieldValue,
  buttonProps,
  menuProps,
  onChange,
  options,
}: OptionMenuProps) => {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);
  const handleClick = useCallback((event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  }, []);

  const handleClose = useCallback((option: string) => {
    onChange?.({ target: { name: optionFieldValue, value: option } });

    setAnchorEl(null);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Button
        endIcon={<ArrowDropDownIcon />}
        onClick={handleClick}
        {...buttonProps}
        sx={{ '& .MuiInputAdornment-root': { paddingRight: '0px' } }}
      >
        {initialOption}
      </Button>
      <Menu
        id='options-menu'
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        open={!!anchorEl}
        onClose={handleClose}
        MenuListProps={{
          'aria-labelledby': 'basic-button',
        }}
        {...menuProps}
      >
        {options.map((option) => (
          <MenuItem
            key={option}
            id='menu-item'
            onClick={() => {
              handleClose(option);
            }}
          >
            {option}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </Menu>
    </>
  );
};
```